# Slide Up/Down with JQuery until a certain height - is this possible?

Tags: jquery, slide

Is it possible to slide a div up (closing it) but not completely ?

I mean, slide up but leave a little of that div displayed, is that possible ?

Thanks in advance,
mem

Comment: You might want to just animate/change the height.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this may work:

```
$("#div").toggle(
function(){
   $("#div").animate( { height:"500px" }, { queue:false, duration:500 });
},
function(){
   $("#div").animate( { height:"50px" }, { queue:false, duration:500 });
});
```

Instead of the `500px` it can just be the original size of the div, and the `30px` can be however much you want to show when it's meant to be hidden.

#### Update from the comments

Here's a fiddle showing that it can allow different heights if declared in a variable. And fading out after animation shouldn't be a problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/HdQSX/

```js
var divTest = $("#test").height();
$("#test").toggle(
function(){
   $("#test").animate({ height: divTest + 'px' }, { queue: false, duration: 500 });
},
function(){
   $("#test").animate({ height:'50px' }, { queue: false, duration: 500 });
});
```

```css
#test {
  display: block;
  background: #FF0000;
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Test</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Two things: 1) We must declare the original div height always? I am asking this because... the height may vary depending on content. 2) If we wish to, after this, fade out that little portion that we have just animate, it will be ok yes?

Comment: Here's a fiddle showing that it can allow different heights if declared in a variable: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/HdQSX/ And fading out after animation shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/
"This method signature was **deprecated** in jQuery 1.8 and **removed** in jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named [`.toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) that toggles the visibility of elements."

Answer (score 3):

I don't recommend using jQuery's animate method because it's sometimes buggy in some browsers.
Animate the slide with CSS transitions is a better choice (according to me), by setting the div height or max-height.

CSS:

```
.expandable {
  max-height: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .3s;
}
```

on click, set max-height with jQuery:

```
$(.someSelector).css('max-height', expandedHeight);
```

Then remove the styling when it's clicked again:

```
$(.someSelector).attr('style', '');
```

You can look at [this demo example](http://codepen.io/calsal/pen/NbKrBz)

Answer (score 2):

The better way to open div to its original height is using slideDown().
The problem is that this function requires div to be hidden before it can open it.
The following way is a little bit ugly but works well:

```
$("#test").toggle(
function(){
   $("#test").css('height', 'auto').hide().slideDown('fast');
},
function(){
   $("#test").animate( { height:'50px' }, { queue:false, duration:500 });
});
```